# How to get the required output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define class Temperature, whose initializer method accepts temperature in fahrenheit unit. 
Define a descriptor class Celsius with two methods namely
**get**,which returns temperature in celsius units.**set**,which allows to change temperature to new value in celsius unit.

```
Input : 1)t1=Temperature(32)   2)t1.celsius=0
Output: 1)32,0.0               2)32.0,0.0
```

1st input refers to fahrenheit value and 2nd input refers to celsius value

```
I have tried to write the code but without success:

class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temp = 0):
        self.temp = temp
    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temp * 1.8) + 32
    def __get__(self):
        return(self.temp)
    def __set__(self,temp):
        self.temp=temp
    desc=property(__get__,__set__)
class Temperature:
   def __init__(self,temp=0):
       self.fahrenheit=temp
       self.celsius=(((self.fahrenheit-32)*5)/9)
       c=Celsius()
       c.desc=self.celsius
       self.fahrenheit=c.to_fahrenheit()

    The output I got is 1)32.0 , 0.0     2)32.0 , 0
```

Please let me if any modification required in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to solve a problem that's trying to teach you about descriptors. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html for more details.

But all that's needed for the problem you're writing a solution for:

```
class Celsius:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return ((obj.fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9

    def __set__(self, obj, celcius):
        obj.fahrenheit = ((celcius * 9) / 5) + 32


class Temperature:
    celcius = Celsius()

    def __init__(self, fahrenheit=0):
        self.fahrenheit = fahrenheit
```

Note a few important differences with your code:

- `Celcius` is instantiated and directly assigned to `celcius` on the class, instead of to an attribute on the Temperature instance, as in your case.
- The descriptor performs the conversion in both directions, without complication on the `Temperature` class.
- Most of the extra code on your implementation didn't do anything; as a general rule, if you add code to try to solve a problem, don't keep it around if it doesn't solve the problem. Less is more in programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your code is so small and precise!!

Comment: Glad to help - if you wouldn't mind accepting it as an answer, that would be much appreciated. (you'd have to click the grey check mark on the left of it)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

class Celsius:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):

    return 5 * (instance.fahrenheit - 32) / 9



def __set__(self, instance, value):

    instance.fahrenheit = 32 + 9 * value / 5
```

class Temperature:

```
celsius = Celsius()



def __init__(self, initial_f):

    self.fahrenheit = initial_f
```

t = Temperature(32)

print(t.celsius)

print(t.fahrenheit)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
class Temperature():
    def __init__(self, fahrenheit):
        self.__fahrenheit = fahrenheit
 
    @property
    def celsius(self):
        return (self.__fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
 
    @celsius.setter
    def celsius(self, value):
        self.__fahrenheit = value * 9/5 + 32
  
    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return self.__fahrenheit
 
    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, value):
        self.__fahrenheit = float(value)
 
t1 = Temperature(32)
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
t1.celsius=0
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).